# Why does not C# documentation XML generator work correctly for COM-imported interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation-generation, xml-comments

When using XML documentation comments in C# to generate documentation .XML file in VS2010 SP1, I noticed it **does not seem to work properly in one particular case**: for **COM-imported interface members** (methods and properties).

Let's have this C# file, taking some types from the MS Word Primary Interop Assembly (which I guess is widely known to most people) as an example:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
namespace TestProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Documentation test class. This documentation references a COM interface: <see cref="_Document"/>
    /// and a method in that interface: <see cref="_Document.Activate"/>, as well as a property
    /// <see cref="_Document.ActiveTheme"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class DocumentedClass
    {
    }
}
```

The resulting .XML documentation file contains this:

```
<member name="T:TestProject.DocumentedClass">
    <summary>
    Documentation test class. This documentation references a COM interface: <see cref="T:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document"/>
    and a method in that interface: <see cref="!:_Document.Activate"/>, as well as a property
    <see cref="!:_Document.ActiveTheme"/>.
    </summary>
</member>
```

When you look closely at the generated XML file fragment, you'll see that the reference to the COM interface is resolved (`T:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document`), but **is not resolved for the interface members** (e.g. `!:_Document.Activate`).

I tried to fully qualify the interface members inside the documentation comments as follows, but the result is the same:

```
namespace TestProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Documentation test class. This documentation references
    /// a COM interface: <see cref="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document"/>
    /// and a method in that interface: <see cref="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Activate"/>,
    /// as well as a property: <see cref="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.ActiveTheme"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class DocumentedClass2
    {
    }
}
```

Now, what is weird is that it seems to work for COM-imported *class members*, e.g. this documentation:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
namespace TestProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Now, let's reference a COM class <see cref="ParagraphFormatClass"/> and its member property
    /// <see cref="ParagraphFormatClass.Alignment"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class DocumentedClass3
    {
    }
}
```

results in the following XML documentation file fragment:

```
<member name="T:TestProject.DocumentedClass3">
    <summary>
    Now, let's reference a COM class <see cref="T:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ParagraphFormatClass"/> and its member
    <see cref="P:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ParagraphFormatClass.Alignment"/>.
    </summary>
</member>
```

which is perfectly valid as the COM class property is resolved correctly to `P:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ParagraphFormatClass.Alignment`.

This really occurs for COM-imported interfaces only, normal interface members are referenced correctly in the resulting documentation XML files. It makes no difference if the COM-imported interface comes from a PIA or if you import the type library yourself via tlbimp.exe.

My question is this: is there a reason for this behavior or is it a bug? What can I do to make the COM-imported interface members be referenced correctly in generated XML documentation files?

Comment: Filed this issue in Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/734928/c-documentation-xml-generator-does-not-work-correctly-for-com-imported-interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting issue. I could reproduce this but for `ParagraphFormatClass.Alignment` it's still incorrect for me. More interestingly, if you actually use those members in your code (in a given method), even in an `if (false)` block, the XML `cref` references are resolved correcly. But unfortunately this trick only works in methods, not classes. So I think you have no choice but to manually type the member reference IDs:

```
<see cref="M:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Activate"/>

<see cref="P:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.ActiveTheme"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried to type the reference manually. The only problem is, I am using Resharper and it seems to underline and complain about certain references like this. Interestingly enough, it does not underline those "invalid" references which are otherwise outputted as a compiler warning. Something is fishy about all this.. :-)

Comment: How did you get it to work with ParagraphFormatClass.Alignment? That could be the right solution...

Comment: The sample in my post just works for me. If it does not work for you, it might mean that the behavior is not 100% consistent.

Comment: No luck for me. This is very, very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a .NET 4.0 app?  If so, it could be caused by the compiler using dynamic types behind the scenes.  If your project contains a reference to Microsoft.CSharp that's an indication that dynamic types could be used.  If you remove the reference and do a build, you'll get compiler errors about it being unable to resolve the types needed for the dynamic code if that is the case.  Doing that in my add-in projects flags the instances where I'm using Document and a few other types as needing the dynamic binder types.  That could be why the compiler resolves the class members but not the interfaces.  For instances where dynamic types are used, they won't be resolved until runtime.  As such, there's nothing there for the compiler to use for the XML comments member ID.  That's my theory anyway.

Comment: I am quite sure dynamic resolution is not the problem here. First, it's not a .NET 4 app (but the problem occurs in .NET 4 as well). Second, it occurs even when used on COM types which do not inherit from IDispatch, most types I am actually trying to reference in my real-world documentation are IUnknown-only. Third, the problem also appears on enumerations (which do get referenced correctly) and their members (which are unresolved).

Comment: What is really interesting - as Balazs discovered in his answer, when you actually use the members in a method body, their references are resolved correctly in the XML file.